# HCL Notes: bug in wAppointmentOpen

Tags: lotus-notes, hcl-notes

One of the mail databases on my client's server is corrupted, or a document in it, well, that's my conclusion after seeing this line in the log:

```
18/04/2023 17:37:40   Agent 'wAppointmentOpen' error: Instance member UPDATENOTICE does not exist
```

That's all the info there is...

I checked the mail template that's used for all mail databases, but none of the libraries containing a reference to UpdateNotice has been modified, they are still signed by Lotus Notes Template Development, dating back to 24 September 2013.

Is there any way I can discover which mail database needs fixing?? Luckily, there are only 20 mail dbs or so on this particular server, but imagine there are 1000 users...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We activated HTTP logging, here's what we found in the domlog.nsf database:

POST /Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync?User=user@domain.org&DeviceId=H14223H4T5O627F8S96&DeviceType=iPhone&Cmd=Sync

It's a request originating from Traveler, which is also installed. So, we know the mail database that's involved.